# How to create a final report from excel filters

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010

This is an excel file with 2 persons:

[image]

If i filter (John) the result is this:

[image]

If i filter (Sally) the result is this:

[image]

Is it possible to force excel to make a table with the following result (With Formula OR VBA):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use formulas like these:
In `A14` :`=INDEX(T(+$A$4:$A$10),MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF(A$13:A13,$A$4:$A$10),),0))`

In `B14` :`=SUMIF($A$4:$A$10,A14,$B$4:$B$10)-SUMIF($A$4:$A$10,A14,$C$4:$C$10)`
As a supplement, alternative formulas to B14 can also be given.

```
=SUMPRODUCT({1;-1},SUMIF($A$4:$A$10,$A14,INDIRECT({"$B$4:$B$10";"$C$4:$C$10"})))
=SUMPRODUCT({1;-1},SUMIF($A$4:$A$10,$A14,OFFSET($B$4:$B$10,,{0;1})))
```

[image: Customers]

Comment: thank you... how to put this table in another sheet?

Comment: You should use the proper addresses in your new location.
`$A$4:$A$10`, `$B$4:$B$10`, `$C$4:$C$10` represent columns of your data.
`A14` is the cell where you start your list of unicates.
`A13` is the cell directly above.
`B14` is the cell where subtotals start.
Formulas from `A14:B14` should be copied down.
If you refer to another sheet you must use notation e.g.:
`Sheet1!$A$4:$A$10`

Comment: Thank you very much... i have forgotten to change the A14 and A13